# Facebook function(response)

Tags: facebook

I use a function on a webpage where people can click a button and publish content on facebook.
After a successfull post on Facebook, I try to get the facebook Username in the  `function(response) {`. But I cant get it to work. Is it possible? Here what I got so far:

```
function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        response.name here, but how - and possible???
    }
```

Thx for help,
Neil

Comment: You will only get any information about the user if the connected to your app first. And then posting does only return the post id, nothing about the user. You could either read the post from the API via this ID (answer should contain the posting user as `from`), or make an API call to `/me` to get user details.

Comment: The user connects through my app, login to facebook and posts into his facebook account. Could you give an example of the needed API call?

Comment: If you are posting successfully via API already, then you should know how API calls work in general. So just do a call for `/me` …

Comment: Im using this function (FB.ui). ANd Im not sure where to put the API call to/me.
`FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);`